# C++: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I receive the error in the title when I try to run this code:

```
//Copies the information from one array to another until a set length using pointers
void strncpy2(char* t, const char* s, const unsigned int n)
{
        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n /* This i < n causes the error */ && *t++ = *s++; i++);
        *(t + i) = '\0';
}
```

When I take out the `i < n` it works fine, and when I move the `i < n` to the right of the `*t++ = *s++` I get no compiling error, however the code doesn't work as intended.

What's going on here?  I appreciate any help.  Thank you!

Comment: No, the single equals sign is intended so that it copies the info from *t to *s.

Comment: Sorry - removed comment. I read it as strcmp.

Comment: Note that this pointer chasing code is not C++-ish but rather C-ish (the question is tagged C++).

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses around the assignment in the loop, since the `&&` operator has higher precedence than the assignment. Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n && (*t++ = *s++); i++);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. I figured it was something simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic of your call is not clear, especially it differs significantly from strncpy().

You seem to manipulate raw string but you don't check for the end of string, which is unsafe.

Moreover the assignment after the loop uses "t" as a base pointer, which is wrong since you modified it.

I don't know what "n" implies on the size of t, if t has to be at least size n, you have to stop iterating at n-2 or your final assignment is out-of-bound.

Finally I stay away from codes that have side effects in the for loop header.

```
void strncpy2(char* t, const char* s, const unsigned int n)
{
        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            t[i] = s[i]; 
            if(s[i] == '\0') return;
        }
        t[i] = '\0';
}
```

if you want to use pointers chasing (c):

```
void strncpy2(char* t, const char* s, const unsigned int n)
{
        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            *t = *s; 
            if(*s == '\0') return;
            t++; s++;
        }
        *t = '\0';
}
```

Now I don't know what is the point of doing that, already having strncpy() and memcpy() in the standard library. And of course, C++ code should avoid raw string ;)